# infinispan file store size disproportional to data size

Tags: java, infinispan

i wrote a small infinispan cache PoC (code below) to try and asses infinispan performance. while running it i found that for my configuration infinispan apparently does not clear old copies of cache entries from disk, leading to disk space consumption that is orders of magnitude more than expected.

what can i do to bring disk usage down to roughly the size of the actual data?

here's my test code:

```
import org.infinispan.AdvancedCache;
import org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class App {
    final static int ELEMENTS_PER_BIN = 1000;
    final static int NUM_OF_BINS = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File storeFile = new File("store/store.dat");
        if (storeFile.exists() && !storeFile.delete()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("unable to delete store file from previous run");
        }

        DefaultCacheManager cm = new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml");
        AdvancedCache<String, Bin> cache = cm.<String,Bin>getCache("store").getAdvancedCache();

        Random rng = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i=0; i<ELEMENTS_PER_BIN; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_BINS; j++) {
                String key = "bin-"+j;
                Bin bin = cache.get(key); //get from cache
                if (bin==null) {
                    bin = new Bin();
                }
                bin.add(rng.nextLong()); //modify
                cache.put(key, bin); //write back
            }
        }

        long expectedSize = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<NUM_OF_BINS; j++) {
            String key = "bin-"+j;
            Bin bin = cache.get(key);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(bin);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            expectedSize += baos.size();
            baos.close();
        }

        long actualSize = new File("store/store.dat").length();

        System.err.println(ELEMENTS_PER_BIN+" elements x "+NUM_OF_BINS+" bins. expected="+expectedSize+" actual="+actualSize+" in "+cache.size()+" elements. diff="+(actualSize/(double)expectedSize));
    }

    public static class Bin implements Serializable{
        private long[] data = null;
        public void add(long datum) {
            data = data==null ? new long[1] : Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length+1); //expand capacity
            data[data.length-1] = datum;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the infinispan configuration:

```
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0">
    <namedCache name="store">
        <eviction strategy="LRU" maxEntries="20"/>
        <persistence passivation="false">
            <singleFile location="store">
                <async enabled="false"/>
            </singleFile>
        </persistence>
    </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

infinispan is (supposed to be?) configured as a write-through cache with 20 latest elements in RAM and a live copy of everything on disk.

running the above code gives this:

> 1000 elements x 100 bins. expected=807300 actual=411664404 in 100
>   elements. diff=509.92741731698254

which means that for 788 KBytes of data i end up with a ~392 MB file!

what am i doing wrong?

the version of infinispan in question is 6.0.2.Final

Answer (score 2):

When you store only longer and longer records, the space used previously is not reused. There's no defragmentation policy in SingleFileStore, free space is kept as a map of list of entry spaces, but adjacent free spaces are not merged.
Therefore, the new entry is always added on the end of the file and the beginning is fragmented and unused.

By the way, for finding out the expected size you should also:

- use JBoss Marshalling instead of Java Serialization
- serialize the key as well
- serialize Infinispan metadata (such as entry lifespan, last use time, possibly version etc...)

Comment: im sure that even with all that overhead a x500 ratio is insane :-)

Comment: Let's do the math, then. For each of the 100 bins you get space occupied by 1, 2 ... 1000, therefore each bin and it's history (free space) is 1 + 2 + ... + 1000 = 1000 * 999 / 2 = 499500 values, where you expect 1000 values. That's where the 500x ratio comes.

Comment: I don't say that it's not insane, but your usage pattern is something SingleFileStore is not designed for. It expects that the distribution of entry sizes will be about constant.

Comment: i understand where the 500 comes from. what i meant was that even if i calculated the expected size "properly" the ratio would still be around the same (and increase with time). i also think my use case should be more common than you think - any use case where you retain data samples of any sort would involve ever-increasing values being stored

Comment: The question is whether this is a good practice - often you don't need to look through all the data when reading (especially reading for update). Recommended way for storing lists like this is to chunk them into limited-size entries with "next-key" reference.
Also, if you had not grew all the entries in synchronized way, newer (shorter) lists would have occupied the space left after older lists.

Comment: that would, to me, be complicating what would otherwise have been a simple straight-forward mechnism to allow for underlying flaws in the infrastructure. it would also make other rrdb-style operations a lot more complicated to write

Comment: Sure, I understand your concerns. I recommend sacrificing simplicity for better performance; that's why people usually use caches - get a better performance.
Anyway, I accept that not being able to work your way is a flaw. Either wait for the PR's to handle this (those PRs were discussed and now are awaiting some updates from the author), update your code to work in different way, or integrate the PRs yourself. It's opensource, it's up to you.